# Using shared-ptr vs. unique-ptr for a specific binary-tree algorithm

Tags: c++11, c++14, binary-tree, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

I have been working on implementing various binary-tree algorithms using smart pointers instead of raw pointers. I have a pretty solid understanding of differences between shared/unique pointers and when to use each but this one specific algorithm has been giving me a lot of trouble.

This is my TreeNode implementation with unique_ptr to their left and right children.

```
struct UniqueTreeNode {

    /*Construction via int value*/
    explicit UniqueTreeNode(const int v) : val(v), left(nullptr), right(nullptr), parent(nullptr) {}

    ~UniqueTreeNode() { std::wcout << L"Destroy: " << val << std::endl; }

    /*Printing Utility for unique_ptr to tree node.*/
    friend std::wostream& operator<<(std::wostream& wout, const std::unique_ptr<UniqueTreeNode>& n) {
        std::wstringstream wss;
        print(n.get(), std::wstring(), wss, Child::LEFT);
        return wout << wss.rdbuf();
    }

    /*Printing Utility shared_ptr to tree node.*/
    friend std::wostream& operator<<(std::wostream& wout, const std::shared_ptr<UniqueTreeNode>& n) {
        std::wstringstream wss;
        print(n.get(), std::wstring(), wss, Child::LEFT);
        return wout << wss.rdbuf();
    }

    /*Printing Utility for tree node pointer.*/
    friend std::wostream& operator<<(std::wostream& wout, UniqueTreeNode* n) {
        std::wstringstream wss;
        print(n, std::wstring(), wss, Child::LEFT);
        return wout << wss.rdbuf();
    }

    /*Enum utility to pick child*/
    enum class Child { LEFT, RIGHT };
    static void print(UniqueTreeNode* n, std::wstring ws, std::wstringstream& wss, const Child& c);

    /*Construction level-by-level via vector*/
    static std::unique_ptr<UniqueTreeNode> construct(const std::vector<int>& v);

    int val; // Data element in node.
    std::unique_ptr<UniqueTreeNode> left, right; // left & right child pointers.
    UniqueTreeNode* parent; // parent raw pointer.
};


/**
* \brief Prints the tree level by level.
* \param n current node being processed.
* \param ws wide-string for storing prefix.
* \param wss appends result incrementally.
* \param c child being considered currently.
*/
inline void UniqueTreeNode::print(UniqueTreeNode* n, const std::wstring ws, std::wstringstream& wss, const Child& c) {
    if (!n) wss << L"Empty Tree";
    else {
        if (n->right) print(n->right.get(), ws + (c == Child::LEFT ? L"│   " : L"    "), wss, Child::RIGHT);
        wss << ws << (c == Child::LEFT ? L"└── " : L"┌── ") << std::to_wstring(n->val) << L"\n";
        if (n->left)  print(n->left.get(), ws + (c == Child::LEFT ? L"    " : L"│   "), wss, Child::LEFT);
    }
}

/**
* \brief Construction of tree via vector elements.
* \param v vector of elements to add.
* \return the tree after its constructed.
*/
inline std::unique_ptr<UniqueTreeNode> UniqueTreeNode::construct(const std::vector<int>& v) {
    if (v.empty()) return nullptr;
    auto it = v.cbegin();
    auto n = std::make_unique<UniqueTreeNode>(*it);
    std::queue<UniqueTreeNode*> q({ n.get() });
    while (++it != v.cend()) {
        auto *x = q.front(); q.pop();
        x->left = std::make_unique<UniqueTreeNode>(*it), q.push(x->left.get());
        if (++it == v.cend()) break;
        x->right = std::make_unique<UniqueTreeNode>(*it), q.push(x->right.get());
    }
    return n;
}
```

The implementation below is my attempt at solving the [Maximum Binary Tree Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-binary-tree/description/)
from leetcode. However, no matter what I try I cannot figure out a way to solve this one using unique-ptrs. Thats simply due to the fact that I need to store a pointer to my node in the std::deque as well as the their subsequent children. Of course I was able to easily do it via shared-ptr children but I was wondering if it was even possible to do this via unique ptrs. I am aware of the possibility to convert the unique_ptr to shared_ptr to take advantage of reference counting but I cannot move a shared_ptr into the right/left children in my unique_ptr nodes. Here is the code with unique_ptrs.

```
uTreeNode ConstructMaxTree(const vector<int>& v) {
    deque<uTreeNode> s;
    for (const auto val : v) {
        auto n = make_unique<UniqueTreeNode>(val);
        while (!s.empty() && s.back()->val < val) {
            n->left = move(s.back());
            s.pop_back();
        }
        if (!s.empty()) {
            s.back()->right = move(n);
        }  
        s.emplace_back(move(n));
    } 
    return move(s.front());
}
```

Here uTreeNode is just an alias for std::unique_ptr. I am also aware that n is moved twice and that isnt allowed for unique_ptrs. I was wondering if anyone had any insight as to what alternatives exist, if any to using a shared_ptr to solve this problem.

Comment: Using smart pointers doesn't forbid raw pointers. You still use them where non-owning pointers are used. Here, I see nothing wrong with having `deque<UniqueTreeNode *> s;`. When it goes out of scope, you'll still have all your objects cleanly held in the tree you created.

Comment: @spectras I actually tried that. However, inside the while loop when I do this `n->left = move(s.back());` I wouldnt be able to move the raw pointer to the left child since its a unique_ptr.

Comment: Even if I was able to somehow move the child to left. This still isn't working for some reason. The raw pointer to n still goes out of scope and if I try to add {3, 2, 1} (the while loop is never entered), the result isnt as expected. I may not have a complete understanding of scoping for the raw pointers to the objects in this case then. It just isnt working as expected.